# javascript - toLocaleTimeString skip date field in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, datetime

I have the below code to show the current date.

```
var date = new Date();
var options = {
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
    day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
};

var todate=date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options);
```

> Saturday, Oct 17, 2015, 1:20 PM

this is working fine in all the browsers except IE8. 
In IE8, it returns

> 1:20:13 PM

.
Can anyone provide any workaround for this?

Comment: IE below version 11 doesn't support the `options` argument: [Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: how to solve this in IE8?  i want to get the output in the same format Saturday, Oct 17, 2015, 1:20 PM

Comment: Ignore IE8 - the one and only solution :)  Or use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com)